# How do I deploy a Tizen application to the Tizen emulator?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I see Tizen has the [Smart Development Bridge](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/dev_env/commands.htm) (sdb, similar to adb for Android), but it doesn't have an 'install' command as the Android Debug Bridge has on Android.

Can someone give me the steps to deploy/execute a Tizen application on the Tizen emulator?

I want to be able to do this outside of the Tizen development environment (these steps are required by QA).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For web applications (widgets:**

```
sdb push app.wgt /tmp/Application.wgt
sdb shell wrt-installer -i /tmp/Application.wgt
```

For widgets using [Command Line Interface tools web-install](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/ide_sdk_tools/command_line_interface.htm)::

```
web-install -w Application.wgt -i application_uri_id.org
```

or using webtizen:

```
webtizen install -w Application.wgt -i application_uri_id.org
```

**For native packages:**

```
sdb push your.tpk /opt/apps/PKGS/Application.tpk
sdb shell pkgcmd -q -i -t tpk -p /opt/apps/PKGS/Application.tpk
```

For native using [Command Line Interface tools native-install](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/ide_sdk_tools/command_line_interface.htm):

```
native-install -p your.tpk
```

using sdb:

```
sdb install /home/user/your.tpk
```

Comment: use C:\tizen-sdk\tools\ide\bin\native-install.bat -p myapp.tpk

Comment: @TolikOdukha Yes the above where tested for Ubuntu, but under Windows all the above work only if there is `C:\tizen-sdk\tools\ide\bin` is set in path environment variable

Answer (score 4):

```
sdb push app.wgt /sdcard/app.wgt
sdb shell wrt-installer -i /sdcard/app.wgt
```

You can see all the commands that eclipse uses to deploy applications in Preferences > Tizen SDK > Web > Launch

Comment: My app is a .tpk file, not a widget, is there an equivalent command for installing a .tpk file?

Comment: .tpk is for native app .wgt is for a Web App !

Answer (score 3):

With Tizen SDK 2.3.1 & above. We can install/uninstall widgets/Apps with

`sdb install Application.wgt`

`sdb uninstall Application.wgt`

`sdb` is like android `adb` shell utility. If its not available on the system path. Go to the directory where it is installed/available and run it along with the path to you widget.

Answer (score 2):

```
sdb push your.tpk /opt/apps/PKGS/your.tpk
sdb shell pkgcmd -q -i -t tpk -p /opt/apps/PKGS/your.tpk
```

This is how eclipse do it. Hope it'll help

Answer (score 2):

since 2.0a there is CLI for this. I will describe how to use 2.0 released in 2012:
C:\tizen-sdk\tools\ide\bin\ there are CLI tools. You need web-install and web-run
1. intall app
   web-install.bat -w tizenapp.wgt
2 Run installed application:
web-run -i XXXXXX
where XXX is aplication id(find it in your config.xml)

For native applications (tpk) same tools available
native-install and native-run
see more in documentation on this tools https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.tizen.native.appprogramming%2Fhtml%2Fide_sdk_tools%2Fcommand_line_interface.htm

Answer (score 2):

1. `sdb push app.wgt /tmp/Application.wgt`
2. `sdb shell wrt-installer -i /tmp/Application.wgt`

Second command is not working for me, `wrt-installer` is not recognised by sdb