# Manually build Tizen apps and deploy

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm following instructions found on this site to manually build my Tizen project: https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Manually_installing_apps

But when I try installing it I get this error:
"## wrt-installer: EKknEHu6Xk installation has failed - installation or update not allowed; invalid mode"

Has anyone else run into similar problems?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `sdb install yourapp.wgt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the time on the device / emulator up to date, because if there is a difference between the OS time that host the IDE and the device/emulator the  widget install fails.

You might want to check other modes of deployment here:  [How do I deploy a Tizen application to the Tizen emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294677/how-do-i-deploy-a-tizen-application-to-the-tizen-emulator/14521625#14521625)

Also if you manually build the `.wgt` package without the IDE there are severally things that could go wrong in `config.xml` file (and having a `config.xml` and an `index.html` is mandatory.)  In this case you can include the `config.xml` here and eventually I can point you  to what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Personally I once tried installing my widget to a device that had time way behind using a fresh certificate. 
Certificate was so fresh that the Gear treated it as invalid because the current time on Gear was **before** issuing time of the certificate!
Hope this case would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Tizen SDK provide command line tools for developer who like console rather than UI environment.

You can try this. Open your console.(In case of Ubuntu , Ctrl+Alt+t )
I suppose you already install Tizen SDK.

```
web-install -w hellotizen.wgt
```

[Tizen SDK Help](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/ide_sdk_tools/command_line_interface.htm)

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use sdb tool from SDK (tizen-sdk/tools):

```
sdb install <full_package_file_path>
```

For example:

```
sdb install ~/workspace/myApp/myApp.wgt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between manually building and installing applications.
To build the app you need to use your certificate - that is why there is SDK. To install app you can use SDK or command line.
I am afraid that right now you are unable to build applications on your own, without signing the application.